# Mass data change via rest api

Tags: api, rest, postman, magento2

I would like to massively change the data in the order,  customer and in the product

I can change the data in a single order using this query:
[POST] https://test-page.com/rest/V1/orders
Body: `{ "entity": { "entity_id": 1, "state":"pending", "status": "pending" } }`

However, I would like to update more than one order status in one order. This is possible ? I would like to do the same in the case of products (inventory) and customers (attributes). Will I find a ready solution somewhere or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 1):

If Server has implemented a proper RESTful API, there is a good chance that it will not allow you to change data at once for multiple entities. Unless the Service Provider has provided a service to update multiple entities at once.

A typical example of POST ops in your case will look like below

```
POST https://test-page.com/rest/V1/orders/<orderNumber>
```

Better check with your provider, or implement a solution to consume a bulk input but call POST operation once for each entity.